# I want to isolate the column 'night bedtime' for those who nap into a new variable, and those who didn't nap into another new variable

Tags: python, pandas

`nap time in bed` variable has some `nan` values and some 'integer' values but the `night bedtime` variable has only integer values. I want to separate the 'night bedtime' column into two columns based on 'nap time in bed' one for those who don't have nap(`nan` values) and the other for those who have nap(integer values).

```
      night bedtime
0     1245.0
1     1163.0
2     1200.0
3     1186.0
4     1161.0
5     1235.0
6     1260.0
7     1321.0
8     1224.0
9     1278.0
10    1185.0
11    1218.0
12    1222.0
13    1226.0
14    1228.0
15    1246.0
16    1243.0
17    1202.0
18    1190.0
19    1218.0
Name: night bedtime, dtype: float64


0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
5     137.00
6      80.00
7     163.80
8     131.25
9     130.67
10    126.60
11    130.40
12    110.20
13    139.33
14    130.00
15    162.75
16    135.00
17    107.00
18     89.40
19    152.67
Name: nap time in bed, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do read the guidelines on how to post questions. Your question is not formulated properly and you haven't formatted code in an intelligible way. Also, you should show which efforts you have done to solve this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [76]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'night bedtime' : [1186,1161,1235,1260,1321],})
    ...: print(df1)
    ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'nap time in bed': [np.nan, np.nan, 137, 163, np.nan],})
    ...: print(df2)
    ...: 
    ...: #Assuming two dataframes same length
    ...: #indentify where no nap time entered
    ...: idx_no_nap = df2.loc[df2['nap time in bed'].isna()].index.tolist()
    ...: 
    ...: #filter night bedtime based on nap or nap
    ...: df_no_nap = df1[df1.index.isin(idx)]
    ...: df_nap = df1[~df1.index.isin(idx)]
    ...: print(df_no_nap)
    ...: print(df_nap)
   night bedtime
0           1186
1           1161
2           1235
3           1260
4           1321
   nap time in bed
0              NaN
1              NaN
2            137.0
3            163.0
4              NaN
   night bedtime
0           1186
1           1161
4           1321
   night bedtime
2           1235
3           1260
```